# How to add color to an item using data-selected

Tags: html, css, custom-data-attribute

When a user clicks on an option to select it, a `data-selected` attribute is added to the `.item`. How do i style this state of the `.item` DIV and give it a border color.

I've tried this but doesnt seem to work

`div[data-selected=".item"]{
        border-color: #333;
      }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add style like this

```
div.item[data-selected] {
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
```

```css
div.item[data-selected] {
  border: 2px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" data-selected="">
  ABC
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

More Specifically if you want to select with the attribute value, you can do like the snippet below

This type of selection is called [**Attribute Selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

```css
div.item[data-selected="value"] {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="item" data-selected="value">
  Having Border
</div>
<div class="item">
  Not Having Border
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style it with following selector

```
div.item[data-selected] {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
}
```

Here is a fiddle for this

https://jsfiddle.net/3hp2v70r/